# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim is not owned by root

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions

Xcode 6.1 got the error after installation of component have done. Xcode installer is the copy from other mac. Pls help me how to solve dyld_sim error....
Thanks

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim is not owned by root.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 41):

I used this command on terminal:

```
sudo chown root /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim
```

This command change the ownership of the file dyld_sim to the root.

Comment: After the chown I get this error "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim is group writable". Any ideas?

Comment: `chmod g-w /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim` fixed it for me. Like @kev, my Xcode was refusing to run, complaining about “group writable” for “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim” 

I fixed this by going to root and using the “chmod” option for "group remove writable" (g-w). Sudo probably would have worked. Anyway, xcode now runs in root and in my usual admin account.

Comment: I am surprised why the person who asked this question doesn't choose your nice answer as the answer!

Answer (score 11):

I have same problem after little research i found the solution,

type following command in terminal:

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

[image]

Enjoy two versions for Xcode Happy Programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Tap on quit and restart the Xcode again and it will open fine. Just had exact same problem and on restart, Xcode opened and worked fine.

Comment: Although this seems weird and that it shouldn't work it have just worked for me on a copy of Xcode 6.1, I'm updating to 6.2 in a very slow connection and I needed to continue working.

Comment: Thanks all bro i have solved the problem by switching another Mac Mini in my company.  I think problem is we have to use  installer file not the copy from other mac

Answer (score 1):

Run following command in **Terminal**

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```